# How do I pass the name and the value to a VueJS function?

Tags: parameters, vuejs2

I have created this form and want to record all fields at blur to a function with name and value to localStorage

I already saved the name of the field but getting undefined value.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="endereco" name="endereco" value="{{ $extratoSiacon['NOME-LOGRADOURO'] }}" @keydown="$event.keyCode === 13 ? $event.preventDefault() : false" @blur="saveItem(this.endereco.value())">
```

The function is as below:

```
saveItem(campo) {
                localStorage.setItem(campo, campo.value)
            }
```

I expect to record:
key: endereco      value: Some Street

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try as below =>

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="endereco" name="endereco" value="{{ $extratoSiacon['NOME-LOGRADOURO'] }}" @keydown="$event.keyCode === 13 ? $event.preventDefault() : false" @blur="saveItem">

saveItem(e) {
                localStorage.setItem(e.name, e.target.value)
            }
```

Comment: Perfect! Works like a breeze! Thank you so much!